# `Duplex.from()` throws `The "iterable" argument must be an instance of Iterable. Received an instance of Object`

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, duplex

Im highly confused. The [`Duplex.from()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/stream.html#streamduplexfromsrc) method can take a object as `src` and creates fromt he object properties `readable` & `writable` a duplex stream:

> converts `readable` and `writable` into Stream and then combines them into Duplex where the Duplex will write to the writable and read from the readable.

Why does my example not work?

```js
const { PassThrough, Duplex } = require("stream");


const loopback = new PassThrough();


const duplex = Duplex.from({
    writable: loopback,
    readable: loopback
});


duplex.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log("Data on duplex", chunk)
});


duplex.write("Hello World");
```

My expected outcome is that the a duplex stream is created, and if so, that outputs the same i give as input. (Same as "echo", or plain passthrough stream)

Error message:

```sh
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
internal/streams/from.js:32
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('iterable', ['Iterable'], iterable);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "iterable" argument must be an instance of Iterable. Received an instance of Object
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at from (internal/streams/from.js:32:11)
    at Function.Readable.from (internal/streams/readable.js:1368:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marc/projects/test-stream/index.js:7:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Can some one explain to my why i cant create a duplex stream from the a object?

Im a bit lost, since the docs say you can pass a object as argument, but the error message says "must be an instance of Iterable". As far as i know, a object is iterable. So whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i found my mistake.

I was using a outdated node verison:

```sh
node -v
v14.19.0
```

I updated to node.js v16 via nodesource (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#deb):

```sh
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And it worked as expected.